# how to launch a download, it asks me which file to open with but i have no idea

Tags: downloads

I download a few items for my school work but cannot launch them. It keeps asking which program to I want to open with. It isnt like windows when it automatically knows.

Comment: Which type of item it is? I mean what is the extension of downloaded file? It may be that there is no program installed, to handle those type of file.

Comment: windows 7 for my school work

Comment: I am asking  about file type not about OS.

Comment: I don't think .pkg file runs under Ubuntu. It runs under on Arch Linux.  and on  Mac OS

Comment: ok how mout this i have a windows 7 laptop but due to a virus i had to reboot and the guy put linux on my laptop. I need to get back to windows for my school work..How do i do that without the cd. Can i just reboot it again?

Comment: What problem you are facing while booting  windows. Recovery of windows depends upon type of errors, you are getting while booting windows.

Comment: I have linux software on my windows computer..I just want my windows back but i dont have the recovery disc

Comment: If you have formatted windows partition while installation of Linux, then you cant recover.

Comment: sorry for all the question, i know nothing about computers..So how do i know if windows was formatted

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you;re trying do launch. If you download *.exe files it won't be executed unless you use particular apps like e.g wine. If it's only a picture or text document, you'd have to know what extension it has e.g. schedule.pdf (pdf is what's called extension). Afte that you can figure out if you're missing an application to execute this file.

Answer (score 0):

The .pkg tends to be a package application. It is used by many programs so you need to install the same program on your home computer that you use at school.

Sometimes adding a .zip to the end of the file name will allow you to open the file as some of the .pkg files are actually zip files.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, the equivalent to Window's `.exe` files are the `.deb` files. You can just click `.deb` files in Ubuntu and they'll install just as easily as with Windows (it's actually easier, since you won't have to go through all those annoying "Next" buttons). So one thing you could do is check for a Ubuntu or .deb version of the programs you're downloading.

Alternatively, I recommend you enter the "Ubuntu Software Center" (look for a shopping bag icon in your left panel) and search for programs similar to the ones you use in Windows.